# Is it worth to create a "temporary css" with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm thinking about creating a script that allows me to create sort of dynamic classes in a style tag. i.e.:

**HTML:**

```
<p class="padding-top-24">test</p>
```

**SCRIPT:**

1. create a `<style>` tag;
2. check if `.padding-top-24` already exists in this  tag, if not, create the class and use her in the element;

But is it worth? I mean, I know that I could simply use `style="padding-top: 24px"`, but what if I want something more specific like a class that the element only has `padding-top: 24px` when the users is on a small screen?

Again, I could use `@media (max-width: 600px) { .pading-top-24px { padding-top: 24px } }`, but I would need to create a `@media` every time that I want something to have differents properties in specific moments.

Wouldn't it be better if I created a script that do it for me every time that I simply use a class? Using specific sizes for creating the medias. Something like:

**HTML:**

```
<p class="s-font-size-20 m-font-size-24">Hello</p>
```

**SCRIPT:**

1. check the class and use/create the media that it should be part of (in this case, "s" stands for "small" or "<600px" and "m" stands for "medium" or "<992px").
2. add a listener to the media and apply that class if the screen size corresponds.

Does it makes sense? Would it be usefull? Does it already exists?

Comment: Use CSS variables maybe and change value using script.

Comment: Part of what you are describing sounds very similar to the functionality Bootstrap provides. You can use the grid system and define different views for different screen sizes. You can also use predefined classes and add them dynamically using javascript

Answer (score 1):

Here is a crude demo, but I think this gives you and idea of how `CSS Variables` can be used to create a more dynamic experience.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if(e.target.matches('button')) {
    let color = document.querySelector('#colorList').value;
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--fontColor', color);
    
    if(color === '#0f0') {
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--fontSize', '40px');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
:root {
    --fontColor: #0069aa;
    --fontSize: 20px;
   
}

.test {
  color: var(--fontColor);
  font-size: var(--fontSize);
}

h1 {
  color: var(--fontColor);
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading Test</h1>
<div class="test">Test</div>
<div class="test">Test</div>
<div class="test">Test</div>
<div class="test">Test</div>
<span class="test">Test</span>
<button>Click</button>
<select id="colorList">
  <option value="#f00">Red</option>
  <option value="#0f0">Green</option>
  <option value="#00f">Blue</option>
</select>
```

Comment: css variables are atually something that I completely forgot lol. But what if you want to specify what css property that you want and its value right in the class as well? Something like "m-padding-0 m-font-size-20" woudn't I need to create by hand all the specific classes into the css file in this way?

Comment: The ideia is to create a script that will automatcally create this new class with it's value at the right @media size

Comment: I think variables is your answer here, with scenario you described you would just have the two properties set as a default value and alter as required.